# Rewriting this python function in c++ seems to make it run a lot slower. Is this reasonable?

Tags: python, c++, performance, breadth-first-search

I'm implementing some graph traversal functions in python but I need better performance so I decided to try to rewrite the functions in c++, but they seem to run slower. I'm a c++ beginner so I'm not sure if this is expected behavior.

The following python functions implements a Breadth-First Search on an unweighted graph. Its objective is to visit every vertex once and measure how many hops away each vertex is from the source.

graph is  `dict {vertex : set(neighbor1, neighbor2 ... , neighbor n) }`

return is `dict {vertex : distance_to_source}`

```
def shortest_path_lengths(graph,source):

seen={}                 
level=0                  
nextlevel={source}     

while nextlevel:
    thislevel=nextlevel  
    nextlevel=set()        

    for v in thislevel:
        if v not in seen:
            seen[v]=level
            nextlevel.update(graph[v])
    level=level+1
return seen
```

And runs:

```
%timeit seen = shortest_path_lengths(G,0)
10 loops, best of 3: 79.7 ms per loop
```

For my c++ implementation:

graph is `map< long vertex, set < long > vertex neighbors >`

return is `map < long vertex ,int distance_from_source >`

```
map<long,int> spl(graph G, long source)
{
    int level = 0;
    map<long, int> seen;
    set<long> nextlevel;
    set<long> thislevel;

    nextlevel.insert(source);
    while (! nextlevel.empty())
    {
        thislevel = nextlevel;
        nextlevel.clear();
        for (auto it = thislevel.begin(); it != thislevel.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (! seen.count(*it))
            {
                seen[*it] = level;
                //cout << G[*it];
                nextlevel.insert(G[*it].begin(), G[*it].end());
            }
        }
        level++;

    }
    return seen;
}
```

and I measure its execution time with:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
seen = spl(graph1,0);
clock_t end = clock();

double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("\nTime taken: %.8fs\n", elapsed_secs);
```

and get output:

```
Time taken: 0.38512900s
```

which is almost 5 times slower than the python implementation for the same graph. Seeing as I'm a beginner in c++, I'm not really sure if I'm measuring time wrong, I'm implementing something wrong, or even if this is expected behavior.

EDIT:
After converting maps into unordered_maps, using the -O2 -flto compile parameters, and passing the graph by const reference, the run time of the c++ function for a graph of size 65k drops down to 0.09sec, which is still a bit slower than pythons 0.08s for the same graph.

On a bigger graph of 75k nodes (but over twice as many edges), c++ falls further behind at 0.3s to python's 0.2s

EDIT2:

After changing the nested set inside the map to unordered_set as well, and changing the thislevel/nextlevel sets also to unordered_sets, the c++ code beats the python code on the smaller graph ( 0.063 to 0.081 sec) but only matches it on the bigger one (0.2 to 0.2)

EDIT3:

On an even bigger graph (85k nodes, over 1.5m edges), python needs 0.9sec for the operation, while the C++ code needs 0.75s

Comment: 1. Optimize your C++ code when you compile it (`-O2`, `-Os` are good GCC/Clang flags for starters, also `-flto` if your compiler supports it...), 2. `map` has logarithmic complexity. In C++, the classic hashmap with constant-time lookup and insertion is `std::unordered_map`. (BTW, are you really running the loop 10 times only? that's not enough. Run it e. g. 100000 times or more.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant that's a complete answer, why are you commenting?

Comment: @djechlin I rarely feel it's worth answering nowadays...

Comment: instead of `thislevel = nextlevel` you can do `thislevel.swap(nextlevel)` since you clear the contents on the next line anyway. More generally you can take advantage of `for ( item : list)` loops in C++11 which are similar to python's `for item in list`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I feel the same way, unless I need the space of the answer to make the code-changes understandable or I feel that I could sufficiently test the code to make 100% sure I solved the problem and explained it, I don't feel like making it an answer. I understand that making answers is more what this site is about but I find commenting ala "oh, I know what that could be" to be more fun

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant but you *just answered right now*. You clicked "add comment" instead of "add answer." It's not worth it to have questions with answers, instead it's better to have questions with comments? Is that your logic? I'm bewildered.

Comment: I've just noticed you are passing `G` in by value which is going to be an expensive copy. It could probably be a `const &` parameter quite easily.

Comment: @sjdowling I changed that as you said, and combined with the g++ optimization compile parameters, I'm now getting times a lot closer to pythons. Still slower tho.

Python runs in ~0.2sec for a graph with 75000 nodes, while the c++ version takes ~0.3sec.

I'm going to try larger graphs soon

Comment: At the end of the day, the *vast* majority of the operations you do in the python code are all optimized and implemented in C anyway. There will be some overhead, but the difference isn't going to be terribly drastic, as you've found as you've continually tried to 'beat' it with your own C++ implementation. At that point, the question comes down to 'is it worth adding the additional complexity of having a compiled extension?' It's up to you to decide that one.

Comment: I was wondering if networkx couldn't do this job sufficiently well; turns out that's the source of the Python function in the first place.

Comment: @Yann Vernier not exactly. Networkx uses a slightly different graph representation in which the neighbors of a vertex are dict keys that can contain attribute values.  I did use their implementation for this particular function for bfs tho you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that jumped out at me is you used a hash map in Python, which is what dictionaries are, and a tree-based map in C++, which is what `set` is. The C++ equivalent is `unordered_map`.

Comment: You mean `std::unordered_set`

Comment: @sjdowling I think he rather meant `map`. The context is key-value storage, so `set` and `unordered_set` don't fly.

Comment: I tried changing the graph into an unordered_map, and the "seen" structure into also an unordered_map, it didn't seem to offer any speedup. The compile flags -O2 -Os -flto halved the time tho

Comment: @pplat perhaps because your graphs are not large enough for constant-time complexity to outweigh logarithmic complexity. Did you try adding compiler optimizations?

Comment: There's no point using `-Os` it will just make things slower.

Comment: Since this is the only answer, I'm accepting it. Special thanks to various comments that also provided help

Answer (score 1):

`thislevel = nextlevel;`

In c++, this makes full copy of the sets. You should rather use pointers to the sets, and swap the pointers instead of the sets.